# Is there a good way of mass deleting GCP batch job logs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

The Google Cloud console is very frustrating especially for Batch when trying to filter job logs when there are 1000+. Is there an elegant way of deleting job logs that are older than 30+ days? Or have succeeded?

I know you can run `gcloud batch jobs delete` or use the API but it seems you can't filter for date created beforehand and then delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `gcloud batch jobs delete` command will delete a job that you wanted to remove from your project.

Based on this documentation on [deleting a job](https://cloud.google.com/batch/docs/delete-job#delete_a_job):

> Delete a job when you are ready to remove it from your project's list of jobs and no longer need the job's history. If you delete a job before or while it is running, the job is canceled.

As of the moment, the option to delete job logs is not yet available. You can only view and/or query your job logs through [Cloud Logging](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query) and you can only query specific sections of Google Cloud Services. You can check the list through this [enter link description here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/query-library).

I would suggest filing this as a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). It's not a guarantee that this feature would be immediately available in the future however you can track its progress once the ticket has been created.

You may also check the documentation below that you may find helpful:

- [Build queries by using the Logging query language](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/building-queries)
- [View logs routed to Cloud Logging buckets](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/using_exported_logs)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, there may be some work underway to improve the experience with old jobs. Here's a script that could be used to delete FAILED jobs in bulk. You can edit the gcloud command to filter by created date. More details on Batch gcloud filters here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/batch/jobs/list#--filter

```html
#!/bin/bash

# Get a list of all failed batch jobs.
jobs=$(gcloud batch jobs list --format="table(NAME)" --filter status.state:FAILED)

# Iterate over each job and delete it.
for job in $jobs; do
    # Making sure the job variable is not the NAME header.
    if [[ "$job" != "NAME" ]]; then
        # Delete the job.
        gcloud batch jobs delete $job
        sleep 1
    fi
done
```